# Vue.js: Defining computed environment variables in vue.config.js (vue cli 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli-3

The documentation for Vue CLI 3 says here https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code:

> You can have computed env vars in your `vue.config.js` file. They still need to be prefixed with `VUE_APP_`. This is useful for version info `process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version`

This is exactly what I want to do. But I couldn't find out how to actually define the env var there in `vue.config.js`. I tried:

```js
module.exports = {
    process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION: require("../package.json").version,
    ...
}
```

But it just produces an error:

```
ERROR  SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    /Users/lhermann/htdocs/langify/frontend/vue.config.js:2
    process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION: require("../package.json").version,
           ^
```

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment variables are not part of the config export, you just set them in the `vue.config.js` file, eg

```js
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version

module.exports = {
  // other config, eg configureWebpack
}
```

I've raised a feature-request to get an example added to the docs ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2864

Comment: Thank you for helping me in my confusion. I just confirmed it indeed works like you suggested!

Comment: @Phil I place the same line of code in my vue.config.js file, it is working on serve but when I generate build then it is not fetching the package.json version number and it's showing undefined in the app.

Answer (score 5):

## Common Environment Variables:

According to [Environment Variables and Modes documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html), you can specify env variables by placing `.env` files in your project root.

The variables will automatically be accessible under `process.env.variableName` in your project. Loaded variables are also available to all vue-cli-service commands, plugins and dependencies.

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

Your `.env` file(s) should look like this:

```
VUE_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value
VUE_APP_ANOTHER_VARIABLE=value
```

**Note that only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`.**

## Computed Environment Variables:

If you want variables that need pre-processing, you can use [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) property of `vue.config.js` to inject anything you want:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('define').tap(args => {
      args[0]['process.env'].APP_VERSION = `"${require("../package.json").version}"`
      return args
    })
  }
  // ...
}
```

Using this method, you can inject anything, with any names you want; you are not bound by the `VUE_APP_` limitation.